# Pulling data between workbooks in excel and displaying pulled data in next available empty column

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to simplify a process that I have to complete each day at work. I currently copy updated data from one excel document to the other.

Rather than copying and pasting the data each day, I would like to use VBA to call in the data from the workbook. This is simple enough and not where my issue lies.

I need the data to be placed in the next empty column as the specifed workbook needs to collect and save the daily data.

```
Sub pull()

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\users\Seanin.Ledgewood\documents\book2.xlsm"

    Dim currentWb As Workbook
    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

    Dim openWs As Worksheet
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = openWs.Range("A1")

    openWb.Close (True)

End Sub
```

simplified version of the code being used. I understand that the code below needs edited and would appreciate any help with this issue

```
 currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = openWs.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to change is (this code will add new data in the first empty column in first row):

```
Dim lastcolumn As Long
With currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Cells(1, lastcolumn + 1) = openWs.Range("A1")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks very much @mehow that is exactly what I was going for.